# client side dynamically created hidden fields lost when postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I programmatically created few hidden fields at client side, inserted into the form.
I verified the form.childElementCount does increased.

```
var disabledState_id = "<%=HidData_DisabledState_Prefix%>" + uiObj.attr("id");
...
disabledState = $("<input type='hidden' id='" + disabledState_id + "' />");
disabledState.appendTo("form");
```

when postback, I can't find these hidden values in Request.Form .
can't find those keys as well in Request.Form.AllKeys, as the id is fixed to a prefix.

Comment: You need to set name attribute

Comment: YES. plz post this as answer so I mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `name` attribute in order to get input value send on FORM submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a code-generated HiddenField, it needs to have the same ID and be created before the Page sets the posted values, such as in OnInit.

The following link may help  you :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

You can use:

```
 protected string disabledState = "";
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      this.disabledState = Request.Form["disabledState"];
 }
```

In javascript you can use the following :

```
 var disabledState ;
     window.onload = function () {
         disabledState = document.getElementById('"+disabledState_id+"');
     };
```

Comment: I'm not creating them at server side, they are fully created at client side.